# Registering a webhook in Dynamics 365

Tags: node.js, dynamics-crm, webhooks, microsoft-dynamics

I use this code to register a webhook in Dynamics

```
webhook = {
      name: `devonso_${organizationId}`,
      contract: 8,
      url,
      authtype: 5,
      authvalue: 'somestring'
    }

    await xrm.create('serviceendpoint', webhook)
```

But i get this error:

> 'AuthValue is Invalid. Please check the value and format and retry the operation.'

I searched the web but couldn't find correct format for authValue